# Does a doublesharp always cancel out a shebang?

Tags: shebang

Would an extra `#` always cancel out the sharp exclamation? As in:

Enabled:

```
#!/foo/bar
```

Disbabled:

```
##!/foo/bar
```

Are there any *known* circumstances where an exec could execute the `bar`? Are there environments where `\x23\x23\x21...` is recognized magic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) has nothing to say either way:

> One common historical implementation is that the execl(), execv(),
>   execle(), and execve() functions return an [ENOEXEC] error for any
>   file not recognizable as executable, including a shell script. When
>   the execlp() and execvp() functions encounter such a file, they assume
>   the file to be a shell script and invoke a known command interpreter
>   to interpret such files. This is now required by POSIX.1-2008. These
>   implementations of execvp() and execlp() only give the [ENOEXEC] error
>   in the rare case of a problem with the command interpreter's
>   executable file. Because of these implementations, the [ENOEXEC] error
>   is not mentioned for execlp() or execvp(), although implementations
>   can still give it.
>
> Another way that some historical implementations handle shell scripts
>   is by recognizing the first two bytes of the file as the character
>   string "#!" and using the remainder of the first line of the file as
>   the name of the command interpreter to execute.
>
> One potential source of confusion noted by the standard developers is
>   over how the contents of a process image file affect the behavior of
>   the exec family of functions. The following is a description of the
>   actions taken:
>
> 1. If the process image file is a valid executable (in a format that is executable and valid and having appropriate privileges) for this
>      system, then the system executes the file.
> 2. If the process image file has appropriate privileges and is in a format that is executable but not valid for this system (such as a
>      recognized binary for another architecture), then this is an error and
>      errno is set to [EINVAL] (see later RATIONALE on [EINVAL]).
> 3. If the process image file has appropriate privileges but is not otherwise recognized:
>
>    1. If this is a call to execlp() or execvp(), then they invoke a command interpreter assuming that the process image file is a shell
>         script.
>    2. If this is not a call to execlp() or execvp(), then an error occurs and errno is set to [ENOEXEC].

You'll note it doesn't specify *how* the command interpreter in 3.1 is identified.

---

But on *Linux*, it is required that shebang begin with `#!` exactly. See [`man 2 execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html):

```
execve() executes the program pointed to by filename.  filename must
be either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of
the form:

   #! interpreter [optional-arg]
```

And `#` is a common enough comment character, which is why `##!` seems to cancel out the shebang without any other effects. However, the script will still be executed using `sh`, so even if `/foo/bar` isn't executed, it may not be what you expected. See [`man 3 exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

```
If the header of a file isn't recognized (the attempted execve(2)
failed with the error ENOEXEC), these functions will execute the
shell (/bin/sh) with the path of the file as its first argument.  (If
this attempt fails, no further searching is done.)
```

I don't know of any system that accepts shebangs other than `#!`, and certainly I doubt whether `##!` will be treated specially, but it's certainly possible - the standard doesn't preclude it.